# Connection string keep connecting as database admin in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am developing my first web site and I am having problems with sql connections with sql server. I am connecting to it via c#. Here is the connection string :

```
string _connectionString = "user id= BadUsername; password= BadPassword; server = MyServer; Trusted_Connection = yes; database= Mydatabase; connection timeout = 30;
```

Even with a bad username and a bad password the connection is a success and I am able to perform select on the database. 
ote that my database has only one user : AdminUser which use windows credential for connection.
I have tried the `sp_who` stored procedure and the user connected by that connection string is the AdminUser. 
So it seems that no matter what I put for username or password in my connection string, the resulting user will be my AdminUser. 
I have disable the guest connection and it's doing the same thing.
Any idea how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of Trusted_Connection = yes;(Windows Authentication)

When false, User ID and Password are taken into account for authentication.
When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Comment: so by putting trusted connection to yes it bypass the credentials I am giving and use the windows creds of the user I am login with on my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try That

```
string _connectionString = "user id= BadUsername; password= BadPassword; server = MyServer; database= Mydatabase; connection timeout = 30;
```